# Why does C++ need array of 6 size to store 5 letter word whereas C allows just 5?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, size

I have tried this following statement in C and C++.

```
char A[5] = {"Hello"};
```

While C accepts this, C++ is throwing an error saying the string is too long. If there is a null character to be added, why is it accepted in C but not in C++?

Comment: _"why its accepting in c but not in c++"_. Because C and C++ are different languages with different rules.

Comment: Note: (at least in C) the braces are redundant ... `char A[5] = "Hello";` is also legal.

Comment: @pmg Without is legal in C++, too – well, provided array length issue fixed already, of course...

Comment: @ThomasSablik To be honest, I feel a bit like in that joke with a helicopter flying around in fog, at a building pilot asking (on a sign held at the window) 'where are we?' – answer (on sign again): 'in a helicopter' [rest omitted]...

Comment: Note that what you get in C is **not** (repeat **not**) a string because [§7.1.1 Definition of terms](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1) — _A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character_ yet there is no null terminator in the array of 5 characters.

Comment: If you really want to use size 5 and work in both C and C++, use `char A[5] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };` where the braces are now required.  That's an array initialized with 5 specified integer character constants (in the jargon of the [C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p2)); there is no automatic null termination added.  Note that if the size were 6 or more, then the remaining uninitialized characters would be set to 0, aka `'\0'`, producing a string as before.

Answer (score 8):

Please note that `char A[5]={"Hello"};` is a bug in either language. There must be room to allocate the null terminator.

It compiles in C because the language 6.7.9/14 has an an odd special rule/language bug, emphasis mine:

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string
>   literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (**including the
>   terminating null character if there is room** or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the
>   elements of the array.

This allows a character array to be initialized with a string literal which has exactly the same amount of characters as the size of the array, but silently discard the null termination.

C++ fixed this dangerous language bug.

Comment: C++ not only fixed the language bug, its a complete different language, with a much more checking type system than C.

Comment: *'exactly'* – null character is included if there's room, but sentence doesn't say anything about what happens with surplus characters if array is even shorter. I personally would thus read that `char a[4] = "hello"` is valid, too (and we are actually in what remains then in the array...). Am I wrong at that point?

Comment: @Aconcagua I think 6.7.9/2 forbids that, implicitly: `No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.`

Comment: Bug in C – if I use `a` as ordinary C-string, sure. It appears totally fine to me in cases I *really* don't need the null-terminator, such as with `write(someFD, a, sizeof(a))`. Am I wrong again?

Comment: @Aconcagua — you can use the non-string (see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58428098/why-c-need-array-of-6-size-to-store-5-letter-word#comment103198644_58428098)) in contexts such as `write()` that do not require a string as input.  You can't use it (reliably) in contexts that require a string, such as `printf("%s\n", a)` — though `printf("%.*s\n", (int)sizeof(a), a)` would be OK, and yes the cast is needed — or passing it to `strcpy()` or any other function that requires a string.  It is **not** a string; it is just an array of 5 bytes (that happen to be printable).

Comment: @Aconcagua I would imagine that this has something to do with the ancient string format in Unix where they didn't use null termination but kept track of the size. That is, the same reason as why `strncpy` still remains in the C language.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Acquired the attitude to formulating my comments prudently – seems as if too much in this case... Fully aware of all the C-string stuff (and the missing cast being UB...), now not sure how I should feel about ;) (actually just wanted rather hint to that it might not *necessarily* be a bug...)

Comment: @Lundin I can't comment on the standard, but I whipped up a small program: https://godbolt.org/z/NozrO9 with `char a[3] = "Hello";`. AVR gcc is one of the only compilers on godbolt that outright rejects that. Most of the others print a warning but accept the code (and the `printf` output is "Hel" in almost all cases).

Comment: @Frodyne Enable strict standard C compilation with `-std=c17 -pedantic-errors`.