# Array of strings will not print single characters

Tags: c, arrays, string, c-strings

I need to print elements of an array of strings, each element consisting of a single character. Generally a 1-D char array could be used but in my case I need to use strings to store these.

I've tried the same code with each element being longer than one character and it seemed to work, however with singular characters I can't figure it out.

```
void hands(){
    char suits[4][1] = {"A", "K", "Q", "J"};
    printf("%s", suits[0]);
}
```

I'd expect an output of "A", instead I get "AKQJ {;W?"

Comment: Try `suits[4][2]` to also make space for the null-terminator. *"Generally a 1-D char array could be used but in my case I need to use strings to store these"* from the snippet that you posted, it's not evident why a `char` wouldn't do the job. All you do is printing them, which you can do with chars as well. As it is currently, your (fixed) code is equivalent to `int main(){printf("A");}`.

Comment: This are NUL-terminated strings. The second array dimension must be at least 2.

Comment: They *won't* be NUL-terminated strings, there was no room for the `NUL`. Since the elements of an array are contiguous, the `printf` runs through them without finding a `NUL` but eventually finds one *somewhere else.*

Comment: @Blaze you can post it as answer I guess, since you've been the first one to catch this

Comment: " but in my case I need to use strings to store these." Why?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel there could be `"10"` I guess in the cards

Comment: @Cid I figured it would be a duplicate, but Vlad posted a good answer now. :)

Comment: @Lundin The proposed duplicate doesn't match the question at all.

Comment: @Ctx I'm still searching for a good one. Basically we need "Are strings null terminated in C?" and the answer should be "Yes, they are. Allocate room for them." This is a FAQ, I answered it the other day [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58428098/why-does-c-need-array-of-6-size-to-store-5-letter-word-whereas-c-allows-just-5/58428179#58428179) but with a C++ aspect.

Comment: Couldn't find one but I can write a community wiki FAQ about how to allocate room for null termination when using strings in C.

Comment: I now wrote a community wiki FAQ here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58526131/what-are-strings-and-how-to-use-them. Changing dupe target.

Answer (score 5):

Either declare the array like

```
void hands(){
    char suits[4][2] = {"A", "K", "Q", "J"};
    printf("%s", suits[0]);
}
```

to reserve one more character to the terminating zero characters of the string literals.

Or declare the array of pointers to the string literals like

```
void hands(){
    char * suits[4] = {"A", "K", "Q", "J"};
    printf("%s", suits[0]);
}
```

If the array is not changed in the function then prefix its declaration with the qualifier `const`. For example

```
void hands(){
    const char suits[4][2] = {"A", "K", "Q", "J"};
    printf("%s", suits[0]);
}
```

Using this declaration of the array as in your question

void hands(){
    char suits[4][1] = {"A", "K", "Q", "J"};
    printf("%s", suits[0]);
}

then instead of the conversion specifier `%s` use the conversion specifier `%c`.

```
printf("%c", suits[0][0] );
```

Or you may leave the conversion specifier `%s` but with modifiers like

```
printf("%1.1s", suits[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on the "string" arrays being 1 character long, there won't be room for a null terminator (that would require the arrays to be at least 2 characters long).  In that case, your options are:

1. print with a "precision" of 1:

   ```
   printf("%.1s", suits[0]);
   ```
2. print as a character:

   ```
   printf("%c", suits[0][0]);
   ```

Comment: @Cid Thanks. I missed the `%`. Corrected.