# How should character arrays be used as strings?

Tags: c, string, c-strings, string-literals, nul

I understand that strings in C are just character arrays. So I tried the following code, but it gives strange results, such as garbage output or program crashes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  char str [5] = "hello";
  puts(str);
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

It compiles cleanly with `gcc -std=c17 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra`.

---

<sub>**Note:** This post is meant to be used as a canonical FAQ for problems stemming from a failure to allocate room for a NUL terminator when declaring a string.</sub>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**A C string is a character array that ends with a *null terminator*.**

All characters have a symbol table value. The null terminator is the symbol value `0` (zero). It is used to mark the end of a string. This is necessary since the size of the string isn't stored anywhere.

Therefore, every time you allocate room for a string, you must include sufficient space for the null terminator character. Your example does not do this, it only allocates room for the 5 characters of `"hello"`. Correct code should be:

```
char str[6] = "hello";
```

Or equivalently, you can write self-documenting code for 5 characters plus 1 null terminator:

```
char str[5+1] = "hello";
```

But you can also use this and let the compiler do the counting and pick the size:

```
char str[] = "hello"; // Will allocate 6 bytes automatically
```

When allocating memory for a string dynamically in run-time, you also need to allocate room for the null terminator:

```
char input[n] = ... ;
...
char* str = malloc(strlen(input) + 1);
```

If you don't append a null terminator at the end of a string, then library functions expecting a string won't work properly and you will get "undefined behavior" bugs such as garbage output or program crashes.

The most common way to write a null terminator character in C is by using a so-called "octal escape sequence", looking like this: `'\0'`. This is 100% equivalent to writing `0`, but the `\` serves as self-documenting code to state that the zero is explicitly meant to be a null terminator. Code such as `if(str[i] == '\0')` will check if the specific character is the null terminator.

Please note that the term null terminator has nothing to do with null pointers or the `NULL` macro! This can be confusing - very similar names but very different meanings. This is why the null terminator is sometimes referred to as `NUL` with one L, not to be confused with `NULL` or null pointers. See answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0) for further details.

The `"hello"` in your code is called a *string literal*. This is to be regarded as a read-only string. The `""` syntax means that the compiler will append a null terminator in the end of the string literal automatically. So if you print out `sizeof("hello")` you will get 6, not 5, because you get the size of the array including a null terminator.

---

> It compiles cleanly with gcc

Indeed, not even a warning. This is because of a subtle detail/flaw in the C language that allows character arrays to be initialized with a string literal that contains exactly as many characters as there is room in the array and then silently discard the null terminator (C17 6.7.9/15). The language is purposely behaving like this for historical reasons, see [Inconsistent gcc diagnostic for string initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296727/inconsistent-gcc-diagnostic-for-string-initialization) for details. Also note that C++ is different here and does not allow this trick/flaw to be used.

Comment: ... and maybe also the `char *str = "hello";` ...`str[0] = foo;` problem.

Comment: Perhaps extend the implication of using `sizeof` to its use on a function parameter, especially when defined as an array.

Comment: @WeatherVane Should be covered by another FAQ here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeof-a-pointer-pointing-to-an-array

Comment: A c string is (part of) a character array in which one of the elements (not necessarily the last) is `0` ... or, depending on context, a pointer to an element of a character array which contains a `0` in a subsequent element.

Comment: I have been using the `char[n+1]` paradigm of explicitly providing room for the null terminator within string declarations for decades. It is a true example of 'self-documenting code'.

Comment: Could introduce term _null character_ for `'\0'` to match the C spec.

Comment: I disagree with the "contiguous sequence of characters" change. This is aimed to teach beginners, not to be some formally correct language-lawyer statement. I did a rollback.

Comment: This post has been expanded and integrated in a broader and more detailed string handling FAQ which can be found at Codidact - [Common string handling pitfalls in C programming](https://software.codidact.com/posts/284849). I no longer post detailed self-answered Q&A at SO.

Answer (score 5):

From the C Standard (7.1.1 Definitions of terms)

> 1 **A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and
>   including the first null character.** The term multibyte string is
>   sometimes used instead to emphasize special processing given to
>   multibyte characters contained in the string or to avoid confusion
>   with a wide string. A pointer to a string is a pointer to its initial
>   (lowest addressed) character. The length of a string is the number of
>   bytes preceding the null character and the value of a string is the
>   sequence of the values of the contained characters, in order.

In this declaration

```
char str [5] = "hello";
```

the string literal `"hello"` has the internal representation like

```
{ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' }
```

so it has 6 characters including the terminating zero. Its elements are used to initialize the character array `str` which reserve space only for 5 characters.

The C Standard (opposite to the C++ Standard) allows such an initialization of a character array when the terminating zero of a string literal is not used as an initializer.

However as a result the character array `str` does not contain a string.

If you want that the array would contain a string you could write

```
char str [6] = "hello";
```

or just

```
char str [] = "hello";
```

In the last case the size of the character array is determined from the number of initializers of the string literal that is equal to 6.

Answer (score 3):

Can all *strings* be considered an *array of characters* (**Yes**), can all *character arrays* be considered *strings* (**No**).

**Why Not? and Why does it matter?**

In addition to the other answers explaining that the length of a string is not stored anywhere as part of the string and the references to the standard where a string is defined, the flip-side is "How do the C library functions handle strings?"

While a character array can hold the same characters, it is simply an array of characters unless the last character is followed by the *nul-terminating* character. That *nul-terminating* character is what allows the array of characters to be considered (handled as) a string.

All functions in C that expect a string as an argument expect the sequence of characters to be *nul-terminated*. *Why?*

It has to do with the way all string functions work. Since the length isn't included as part of an array, string-functions, scan forward in the array until the *nul-character* (e.g. `'\0'` -- equivalent to decimal `0`) is found. See [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/). Regardless whether you are using `strcpy`, `strchr`, `strcspn`, etc.. All string functions rely on the *nul-terminating* character being present to define where the end of that string is.

A comparison of two similar functions from `string.h` will emphasize the importance of the *nul-terminating* character. Take for example:

```
    char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

The `strcpy` function simply copies bytes from `src` to `dest` until the *nul-terminating* character is found telling `strcpy` where to stop copying characters. Now take the similar function `memcpy`:

```
    void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
```

The function performs a similar operation, but does not consider or require the `src` parameter to be a string. Since `memcpy` cannot simply scan forward in `src` copying bytes to `dest` until a *nul-terminating* character is reached, it requires an explicit number of bytes to copy as a third parameter. This third parameter provides `memcpy` with the same size information `strcpy` is able to derive simply by scanning forward until a *nul-terminating* character is found.

(which also emphasizes what goes wrong in `strcpy` (or any function expecting a string) if you fail to provide the function with a *nul-terminated* string -- it has no idea where to stop and will happily race off across the rest of your memory segment invoking *Undefined Behavior* until a *nul-character* just happens to be found somewhere in memory -- or a Segmentation Fault occurs)

That is *why* functions expecting a *nul-terminated* string must be passed a *nul-terminated* string and *why it matters*.

Comment: I like this answer, in that it introduces the idea of an additional layer of semantics on strings. An array of `char` is just that. Now, I can define a string to be *“an array of characters, the last of which has value 0”*. But I could also define it in another way (eg: *“an array of characters, the first of which indicates how many follow”* - aka pascal strings). It is not that a string must end with a 0, but that the C library defines the word string to have that meaning.

Comment: Yep, the semantics are C (and `.c_str()` in C++), Pascal strings or concepts in other languages do things differently. The goal is the same. Imagine a Pascal string with the length information missing `:)`

Answer (score 0):

### Intuitively...

Think of an array as a variable (holds things) and a string as a value (can be placed in a variable).

**They are certainly not the same thing.** In your case the variable is too small to hold the string, so the string gets cut off. ("quoted strings" in C have an implicit null character at the end.)

However it's possible to store a string in an array that is *much larger* than the string.

Note that the usual assignment and comparison operators (`=` `==` `<` etc.) don't work as you might expect. But the `strxyz` family of functions comes pretty close, once you know what you're doing. See the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/) on [strings](http://c-faq.com/charstring/index.html) and [arrays](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).