# Difference of a char array in C and C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c, char

I am converting a large code base form C to C++. I got a compiler error for the following line of code:

```
char SingleDigit[2] = {" \n"};
```

> error: a value of type "const char [3]" cannot be used to initialize
> an entity of type "char [2]"

`" \n"` has just one whitespace.

Has the initialization of a char array changed for `C` to `C++`? Is `" "` (with one space) actually a char array of length to (null termination).

Was this a bug in `C` already?

I use the Intel compiler version  19.1.1.216 and Windows 10 for the `C` and the `C++` code.

Comment: In C the 0-terminator does not have to fit into the array, but in C++ it must. It is probably a bug in C, but a constraint violation in C++.

Comment: I tested it with `print("%d",'\n')` and I receive `10` as result. So possibly that compile assume the zero termination in `" \n"` as `" \n\0"`

Comment: See [How should character arrays be used as strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58526131/how-should-character-arrays-be-used-as-strings)