# visual studio triggered a breakpoint when used pointer and strncat

Tags: c, visual-studio, pointers, malloc, strcat

I am implementing the JSON packetizer with the following code

```
int main()
{
  char* serializedMessage;
  serializedMessage = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* 1024);

  if (serializedMessage != NULL)
  {
    strcat(serializedMessage, "{\"");
    strncat(serializedMessage, "\":", 3);
    strncat(serializedMessage, "{", 1);
    strncat(serializedMessage, "\"ds\":[", 8);
    strncat(serializedMessage, "}", 1);
    std::cout  <<serializedMessage <<std::endl;
   }
  return 0;
}
```

when run in visual studio, it throws error as triggered a breakpoint. What i am missing. Any advice

Comment: the integer in `strncat` should match how many chars you are appending. I am not sure, but `"\":"` aren't two chars? (you are escaping one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use `strcat` family of functions on targets that are *C strings*. `serializedMessage` in your code is not yet a C string, it's a chunk of uninitialized memory. [How should character arrays be used as strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58526131/how-should-character-arrays-be-used-as-strings)

Solve this by adding a null terminator at the beginning, to form an empty string:

```
if (serializedMessage != NULL)
{
  serializedMessage[0] = '\0';
  ...
```