# Having issues while using %s

Tags: arrays, c, parsing, printf

I am working on a project in which I extract data received from GPS and save it in array named rx_data_buffer:

```
uint8_t rx_data_buffer[84] = {0};
```

The result I get is as below(see rx_data_buffer) :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD9jh.png)

Then I extract the data from rx_data_buffer in following arrays:

```
uint8_t lattitude[10] = {0};
uint8_t longitude[10] = {0};
uint8_t altitude[5] ={0};
```

The data is extracted as follows:

```
for (uint8_t i =0; i < 10; i++)
{
  lattitude[i] = rx_data_buffer[i+17];
}
for (uint8_t j =0; j < 10; j++)
{
  longitude[j] = rx_data_buffer[j+31];
}
for (uint8_t k =0; k < 5; k++)
{
  altitude[k] = rx_data_buffer[k+56];
}
```

The results are as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6gLV.png)

Till here everything is working fine but when I put the latitude, longitude and altitude data in an array using %s for the purpose of saving them in SD card as follow:

```
snprintf(mystring, sizeof(mystring), "\n%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%d,%s,%s,%s",           readAccelerometer(X_AXIS),readAccelerometer(Y_AXIS),readAccelerometer(Z_AXIS),readGyro(X_AXIS),          readGyro(Y_AXIS),readGyro(Z_AXIS),readMagnetometer(X_AXIS),readMagnetometer(Y_AXIS),         readMagnetometer(Z_AXIS),heart_rate,longitude,lattitude,altitude);
```

I get the longitude and altitude values fine but am getting wrong latitude value in a sense that it show both the values combine as shown below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l1DG.png).

What can be the issue?

Comment: It's ok to post pictures of debug windows etc but please don't post pictures of the actual code. Code needs to be posted as text.

Comment: You have not added a null terminator to any of your arrays.

Comment: Duplicate: [How should character arrays be used as strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58526131/how-should-character-arrays-be-used-as-strings)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now working great when added null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be used as strings, the arrays need a null terminator.  Since you are initializing the arrays to zero, the simplest solution is to make them one larger than you need.  eg:

```
uint8_t lattitude[11] = {0};
uint8_t longitude[11] = {0};
uint8_t altitude[6] ={0};
```

As long as you never write over the last element in the array, it will remain `'\0'` and you can use the string functions.

Comment: Thanks issue solved after adding null terminator at end of each array.