# Why C dosen't split correctly arrays?

Tags: c, string, split

I have an array of 64 characters, which I need to divide into two parts, the left part of 32 characters and the right part, also 32 characters.

```
char *IP_M; // 64 characters array
char L[32]; // left part
char R[32]; // right part
```

The IP_M array is filled in as follow:

```
char *start_inital_permutation(const char *input) {
    char *output = malloc(64 * sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            output[i * 8 + j] = input[IP[i][j] - 1];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
...
IP_M = start_inital_permutation(M);
```

where M is also a 64 characters string. With the following method I tried to fill the other two array (L, R) by spliting the IP_M.

```
void fill_LR() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        L[i] = IP_M[i];
        R[i] = IP_M[i + 32];
    }
}
```

but when I run the following instructions:

```
printf("IP_M: %s\n", IP_M);
printf("L: %s\n", L);
printf("R: %s\n", R);
```

the output is:

```
IP_M: 1100110000000000110011001111111111110000101010101111000010101010
L: 1100110000000000110011001111111111110000101010101111000010101010
R: 11110000101010101111000010101010
```

I can't get out of this situation, can someone help me please?

*EDIT: also tried the `memcpy()` method but it still not work!
Here is the Project if someone want to see it:
https://github.com/ionutbogdandonici/DES_C.git

Comment: The code you've posted is nice and compact, but doesn't compile. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72436704/what-are-null-terminated-strings

Comment: Hint: How does printf know how long the string is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in C are `\0` terminated. So the print function will print the string until it reaches the `\0` character.

Assign space for null:

```
char L[33]; // left part
char R[33]; // right part
```

Add null terminator:

```
void fill_LR() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        L[i] = IP_M[i];
        R[i] = IP_M[i + 32];
    }
    L[32] = 0;
    R[32] = 0; 
}
```

Comment: Yeah! But why my L that have a size of 32 is filled up to 64 characters? The for runs assigns the value till i become 31

Comment: @BOGDANDONICI Where do you see it filled up with 64 characters? If there is no `\0` byte after the 32 characters, `printf` will just continue in adjacent memory until it finda a `\0` byte, no matter which variable is the memory belonging to.

Comment: So what should I do? Simply increment the size of the array by one and fill the position L[32] with ‘\0’?

Comment: @BOGDANDONICI Yes, see the edit of Gerhardh (thanks!)

Comment: That was the edit of another Gerhard ;)

Comment: @BOGDANDONICI Most likely, `R` comes immediately after `L` in memory since they're declared sequentially. And most likely, the first byte following the last value in `R` is coincidentally zero (zero is a common value in uninitialized memory. Volatile memory is zeroed out when the machine is rebooted, and some platforms zero-out memory when freed). In other words, there might "accidentally" be a zero following `R`. Zero is the null terminator, so when you print `L`, it's probably starting at `L` and continuing all the way through `R` until it hits that accidental null terminator. But it's UB.

Answer (score 0):

Using `printf` with **"%s"** assumes the value is a [**zero terminated string**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) (AKA NULL terminated string).
I.e. a pointer to a sequence of `chars`, ending with a `\0` `char`.

In your case when `printf` attempts to print `L` it prints `char`, and after the 32 `char`s that belong to `L` it continues. It happened to be that `R` is following `L` in memory, and so the content of `R` is also dumped. If the next byte in memory following `R` was not a `0`, you would see even more characters printed. This behavior is dependent on the [possibly atrbitarary] content of your memory.

**How to handle the issue (2 ways):**

**1.** You can either increase the size of `L` and `R` to 33, and assign the last char to `\0`:

```
char L[33]; // left part
char R[33]; // right part
/* ... */
L[32] = '\0';
R[32] = '\0';
```

**2.** Or specify to `printf` the length of the strings (32) like this:

```
/*----------vvv-------*/ 
printf("L: %.32s\n", L);
printf("R: %.32s\n", R);
```

In the later case keep in mind that `L` and `R` are not "regular" C strings, which are expected to be **zero terminated** (at least as far as it concerns common functions like `strlen`, `strcmp` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

- `output[i * 8 + j] = input[IP[i][j] - 1];` is gibberish.
- Strings in C are null terminated but you never allocate space for a null terminator anywhere, nor do you null terminate your strings.
- Don't use global variables.

I was able to salvage your program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *start_inital_permutation(const char *input) {
    size_t count=0;
    char *output = malloc(64 * sizeof(char) + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            output[i * 8 + j] = input[count++];
        }
    }
    output[64] = '\0';
    return output;
}

int main()
{
    const char input[] = "1100110000000000110011001111111111110000101010101111000010101010";
    char *IP_M = start_inital_permutation(input);
    char L[32+1]; // left part
    char R[32+1]; // right part
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        L[i] = IP_M[i];
        R[i] = IP_M[i + 32];
    }
    L[32] = '\0';
    R[32] = '\0';

    printf("IP_M: %s\n", IP_M);
    printf("L:    %s\n", L);
    printf("R:    %s\n", R);
}
```

---

However, there's no apparent reason why you need to do the middle step with the 64 characters array. You could as well put that one in a union and save the copy (although then the individual left/right strings won't be null terminated). Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef union
{
  char data [64+1];
  struct
  {
    char left[32];
    char right[32];
    char zero;
  };
} ip_t;

ip_t *start_inital_permutation(const char *input) {
    size_t count=0;
    ip_t* obj = malloc(sizeof(ip_t));
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            obj->data[i * 8 + j] = input[count++];
        }
    }
    obj->data[64] = '\0';
    return obj;
}

int main()
{
    const char input[] = "1100110000000000110011001111111111110000101010101111000010101010";
    ip_t *IP_M = start_inital_permutation(input);

    printf("IP_M: %s\n", IP_M->data);
    printf("L:    %.32s\n", IP_M->left);
    printf("R:    %.32s\n", IP_M->right);
}
```