# Why is the first char* null in this char **?

Tags: c, malloc

I am working on a few functions that will work together to initialize a list of `char *`'s as a command list. I am storing them in a `char **`, which I want to alter whenever it's necessary to insert another command. When I run the insert command with a single char *command, It says that `commandList[0] = "ls"` inside of the insert function, but in the `initializeCommands` function it says that `testCommands[0] = NULL`. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
void insertCommand(char *command, char **commandList){
    if(commandList[0] == NULL){ // no commands
        commandList = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2);
        commandList[0] = (char *)malloc(strlen(command) * sizeof(char));
        commandList[0] = command;
        printf("Commandlist[0]: %s\n", commandList[0]);
        commandList[1] = NULL;
    } else { // one or more commands
        int i = 0;
        while(commandList[i] != NULL){
            i++;
        }
        commandList = (char **)realloc(sizeof(char *) * (i + 1));
        commandList[i - 1] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(command));
        commandList[i] = NULL;
    }
    return;
}
```

The printf statement above shows that commandList[0] != NULL

```
char **initializeCommands(){
    char **testCommands = createCommandList();
    insertCommand("ls", testCommands);
    printf("testCommand[0]: %s\n", testCommands[0]);
    return testCommands;
}
```

The printf statement above shows that testCommands[0] == NULL

create command list

```
char **createCommandList(){
    char **commandList = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
    commandList[0] = NULL;
    return commandList;
}
```

Comment: In C you cannot copy a string with an assignment. You must use `strcpy` to copy the string in the freshly allocated memory. Instead of `commandList[0] = command;` use `strcpy(commandList[0] , command);`. Moreover you have to allocate space for the terminating null, so `commandList[0] = (char *)malloc(strlen(command) + 1);`. You don't need the `sizeof(char)` which is always the base size.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1 and redundant in `sizeof(char) * strlen(command)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C uses [pass by value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value).

`commandList` is a local variable in `insertCommand`, completely independent of  `testCommands` in `initializeCommands` (except `commandList` is initialized from `testCommands` once, at the beginning of the execution of `insertCommand`). Assigning a new value to `commandList` has no effect on `testCommands` or anything else outside of `insertCommand`. Whatever value `testCommands` has before the call to `insertCommand`, it will have after the call.

The interface of `insertCommand` is completely broken. A function that allocates a block of memory to be consumed outside **should return a pointer to it**. (Or, alternatively, assign it to something visible outside of the function, but don't do this unless you cannot return a value for some reason).

The implementation of `insertCommand` is broken too because there is a memory leak.

```
if(commandList[0] == NULL){ 
    commandList = ....  // <--- here
```

This throws the previous value of `commandList` out of the window (and there *is* a previous value, otherwise `commandList[0]` would be illegal).

In fact, either the "then" part of that "if" or the whole `createCommandList` is completely redundant. If you are using `createCommandList`, just the `else` part of that `if` will work just fine. Alternatively, you can get rid of `createCommandList` and just pass `NULL` as an empty list. Don't forget to change `if(commandList[0] == NULL)` to `if(commandList == NULL)` if you do.

Yet another problem is inconsistency between the "then" part and the "else" part.

```
commandList[0] = command;
```

This copies a pointer.

```
commandList[i - 1] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(command));
```

This allocates a whole new buffer, but you forgot to copy `command` to it, and you also forgot about the [null terminator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72436704/what-are-null-terminated-strings).