# Allocating and freeing memory in C

Tags: c, malloc

I'm trying to paste two strings together. I know you can do it faster but I'm not allowed to use build-in functions.
I allocate memory for string3 and in main the memory should be released but it is not.
I'm not allowed to change anything in main. What am I doing wrong?

Allocating memory happens here:

```
 char *string_cat( char const *string1, char const *string2 )
{
    int lengte1 = string_length(string1);
    int lengte2 = string_length(string2);
    int totaal_lengte = lengte1+lengte2;
    char *string3 = (char*) malloc(totaal_lengte*sizeof(char));
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(string1[i] != '\0'){
        string3[j] = string1[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while(string2[i] != '\0'){
        string3[j] = string2[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    return string3;
}
```

Freeing memory happens here:

```
 int main( int argc, char **argv )
    {
        char *str;
        
        printf( "== string_cat ==\n" );
        check( strcmp( ( str = string_cat( "", ""       ) ) == NULL ? "" : str, ""      ) == 0, __FILE__, __LINE__ ); free( str );
        check( strcmp( ( str = string_cat( "", "abcdef" ) ) == NULL ? "" : str, "abcdef" ) == 0, __FILE__, __LINE__ ); free( str );
        check( strcmp( ( str = string_cat( "a", "bcdef" ) ) == NULL ? "" : str, "abcdef" ) == 0, __FILE__, __LINE__ ); free( str );
        check( strcmp( ( str = string_cat( "ab", "cdef" ) ) == NULL ? "" : str, "abcdef" ) == 0, __FILE__, __LINE__ ); free( str );
        check( strcmp( ( str = string_cat( "abc", "def" ) ) == NULL ? "" : str, "abcdef" ) == 0, __FILE__, __LINE__ ); free( str );
        check( strcmp( ( str = string_cat( "abcd", "ef" ) ) == NULL ? "" : str, "abcdef" ) == 0, __FILE__, __LINE__ ); free( str );
        check( strcmp( ( str = string_cat( "abcde", "f" ) ) == NULL ? "" : str, "abcdef" ) == 0, __FILE__, __LINE__ ); free( str );
        check( strcmp( ( str = string_cat( "abcdef", "" ) ) == NULL ? "" : str, "abcdef" ) == 0, __FILE__, __LINE__ ); free( str );
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Post code as properly formatted text. [Edit] your question.

Comment: Hint: the memory space required for a string is the length of the string **plus one** for the null terminator.

Comment: You do seem to remember that strings in C are null-terminated. But you have forgotten that this null-terminator is not counted by `strlen` and that you need to allocate space for it as well. So a string of `X` character needs space for `X + 1` to include the null-terminator.

Comment: And, kinda like Beyoncé sang, not only do you need space for the extra char, but you gotta "put a ring on it..." (ie. fill that extra char with '\0'...) Otherwise it's just an array of characters, not a "string"...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are null-terminated strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72436704/what-are-null-terminated-strings)

Answer (score 4):

1. Do not cast the result of `malloc`. It you are getting the error it means that you compile C code using C++ compiler which is not right.
2. You need extra space for null terminating character.
3. `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1, but if you want to check it (for example strings can be multibyte chars - use objects not types in `sizeof`
4. Use the correct type for size (ie `size_t`)
5. You can modify while loops to include null terminating character in the last copy
6. Chech the result of malloc
7. It is good to check if parameters are OK

```
size_t string_length(const char *s)
{
    const char *end = s;
    while(*end) end++;
    return end - s;
}

char *string_cat( char const *string1, char const *string2 )
{
    char *string3 = NULL;
    if(string1 && string2)
    {
        size_t lengte1 = string_length(string1);
        size_t lengte2 = string_length(string2);
        size_t totaal_lengte = lengte1+lengte2;
        char *tmp;
        string3 = malloc((totaal_lengte + 1) * sizeof(*string3));

        if(string3)
        {
            tmp = string3;
            while(*string1) *tmp++ = *string1++;
            while((*tmp++ = *string2++));
        }
    }
    return string3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to allocate the memory +1, with malloc you maybe need to set
  the last value to '\0' with calloc it will initialize the    memory
  to zero.
- You can override the default functions with your own, not a big thing
  but helps with reading the code.
- Its better to compare constants first to the variable like '\0' ==
  val, this will prevent mistakes like val = '\0'.
- Put free on a new line, this is for readability and makes things less
  confusing.
- This is more of personal opinion, but I don't see the need for space
  between brackets as it just increases the file size with no benefit,
  instead I would use new lines more.
- Its stated and is a minor thing but casting from void to char is not a C thing.

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

size_t strlen(char const* str) {
   size_t i;
   for (i = 0; '\0' != str[i]; i++);
   return i;
}

void* memcpy(void* restrict dst, const void* restrict src, size_t bytes) {
   char* d = dst;
   const char* s = src;

   for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
      d[i] = s[i];
   }

   return d;
}

char* string_cat(char const* str1, char const* str2) {
   int len1 = strlen(str1);
   int len2 = strlen(str2);
   
   /// calloc will set memory block to zero
   char* out = calloc(1, len1 + len2 + 1);

   memcpy(out, str1, len1);
   memcpy(&out[len1], str2, len2);

   return out;
}

int check(int state, const char* file, int line) {
   if (!state) {
      printf("File %s on line %d is not the same\n", file, line);
   }
   return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        char *str;
        
        printf("== string_cat ==\n");
    check(strcmp((str = string_cat("", "")) == NULL
         ? "" : str, "") == 0, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    free(str);
        
    check(strcmp((str = string_cat("", "abcdef")) == NULL
         ? "" : str, "abcdef") == 0, __FILE__, __LINE__); 
    free(str);

        check(strcmp((str = string_cat("a", "bcdef")) == NULL 
         ? "" : str, "abcdef") == 0, __FILE__, __LINE__); 
    free(str);
        
    check(strcmp((str = string_cat("ab", "cdef")) == NULL 
         ? "" : str, "abcdef") == 0, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    free(str);
        
    check(strcmp((str = string_cat("abc", "def")) == NULL 
         ? "" : str, "abcdef") == 0, __FILE__, __LINE__); 
    free(str);

        check(strcmp((str = string_cat("abcd", "ef")) == NULL
         ? "" : str, "abcdef") == 0, __FILE__, __LINE__); 
    free(str);
        
    check(strcmp((str = string_cat("abcde", "f")) == NULL 
         ? "" : str, "abcdef") == 0, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    free(str);
        
    check(strcmp((str = string_cat("abcdef", "")) == NULL
         ? "" : str, "abcdef") == 0, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    free(str);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {` definitely not good

Comment: do not use memcpy as the name of your function.

Comment: I assume that you have copied the code of `memcpy` from somewhere as you do not use `restrict` in any of your other functions.

Comment: Use of expensive function `calloc` makes no sense here.

Comment: @0___________ care to specify?

Comment: @0___________ If you are not going to use the standard function, then I see no harm in this and if you wanted to access the function you still could.

Comment: @0___________ no I don't copy code, the reason for the restrict is that I don't like compiler warnings.

Comment: @0___________ calloc will initialize the allocated memory to 0 while malloc will not, if you copy the null terminator this is not a problem but if you don't then the string might be null terminated or it could not be terminated.