# When the parameter of strlen is a non zero terminated string, its return value is unsafe in IF statesments?

Tags: c, linux, strlen

I have been troubled by a problem of `strlen` for a long time, here is the code:

```
   char stack_protect[1000] = {0};
    char temp[100] = { 0 };
    memset(&temp, 1, 110);
    int len = strlen(temp);
    
    printf("test strlen of temp %d \n", len);
    if (len > 100)
    {
        xxxx;
    }
    else
    {
        xxxx;
    }

   char stack_protect2[1000] = {0};
```

you can see, I passed a param `temp` to `strlen`, and the return value `len` is surely `110`.
but the next statements `if (len > 100)` evaluates to false!

system: linux
CPU architecture: 32 Bit ARM
SOC: nt98566

please help me! thank you

something I have test:

1. if you assign `len` value to another `int` variable, things will ok. like below

example:

```
    char temp[100] = { 0 };
    memset(&temp, 1, 110);
    int len = strlen(temp);
    
    int len1 = len;
    
    if (len1 > 100) ? TRUE!
```

2. the every byte of len:

```
   0x6e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
```

3. in another soc hisiv300
   len:110
   if len > 100? TRUE

Comment: Using string functions on strings that are not NUL terminated is undefined behaviour. Strictly speaking, an array of characters that isn't NUL terminated isn't technically even a string to begin with.

Comment: *"the return value `len` is surely 110"* I'm curious about why do you think so. Do you expect uninitialized memory to always be nulled or `memset` to somehow add a NULL terminator *after* the values it sets? Both are wrong assumptions, to be clear.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "non zero terminated string".  By definition (in C), a "string" is a sequence of non-zero bytes terminated by a single zero byte.  You can certainly have an array of characters that are not terminated by a nul byte, but that array is *not* a "string".  By definition.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72436704/what-are-null-terminated-strings).

Comment: why I think len is 110:  before and after this statement, I declared and initialized an array[1000] with 0.

Comment: If the set collection of characters is not nul-terminated -- it's not a C string. Passing it to a `str...()` function results in *Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: Please note that in an optimized build those two "stack protect" will be ignored (optimized away), also, in general, you can't assume that those variables are packed, they are likely alligned to some multiple of bytes.

Answer (score 6):

`memset(&temp , 1, 110);` is bad as it attempts to write outside the `temp[]` array.  This is **undefined behavior** (UB).  *Anything* may happen at this point, in [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76982587/when-the-parameter-of-strlen-is-a-non-zero-terminated-string-its-return-value-i/76982619#comment135710317_76982619) or in later code.

`strlen(temp);` is also UB as `strlen()` expects a pointer to a *string* and array `temp` is **not** a *string* as it lacks a *null character*.

Do not expect code to behave well when it has UB.
Do not expect code to fail when it has UB.
Do not expect the UB you see today to be the same tomorrow.

Instead, eliminate the UB.

```
char temp[100] = {0};
//memset(&temp , 1, 110);
memset(temp , 1, 99); // Re-write the first 99, leaving the last as 0
int len = strlen(temp);
```

---

I suspect OP's code UB is the writing of `len1` by `memset()`, yet that is only a guess.

Comment: Re “Anything may happen at this point or in later code”: The C standard does not specify what happens at any time, [including before a nominal point at time at which a statement inducing undefined behavior is executed](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633). Consider that, if some branch of execution containing `a[i] = Value;` is executed, the compiler is allowed to assume `i` is not out of bounds and thus may optimize the code as if it is in bounds, so it may put `a[i] = Value;` at the beginning of that path of execution.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Answer amended.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Nice comment. Didn't know it would affect code that comes before the offending code :)