# Extract characters from char array in C

Tags: c, char

I am trying to extract two last characters from a `char` array and has been unable to do so. The array will be given to me and I don't have control over it. I only know the last `n` positions of the array are digits. In the following case `n=2`:

```
char c[5] = "xyz45"
char d[2];
d[0] = c[3];
d[1] = c[4];
int e = atoi(d);
```

Clearly the value of `e` required is `45`. Any way to solve this? (The above approach is a representative way about how one might go about doing this in python. I am looking for an elegant way to do this.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72436704/what-are-null-terminated-strings

Comment: `printf("%s\n", strchr(c, '\0') - 2)` if you make `c` a proper nul terminated string (it isn't in the code you provided)

Comment: @DuttaA, `printf("%d\n", atoi(d));` fails as `d[]` is not a _string_ as required by `atoi()`.

Comment: `char c[5] = "12345"` doesn't leave room for the NUL terminator. That should be `char c[6] = "12345"` or better yet `char c[] = "12345"`, let the compiler figure out the length.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I am being given c. It is not something I have control over.

Comment: @DuttaA, Try `printf("%.2s\n", &c[sizeof c - 2]);`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks...it does work, but I was wondering whether their is any way to extract just 4 and 5 or some indices i,j,k,l.... Your solution works for me, but I would pefer a much more general solution.

Comment: @DuttaA What output do you want with `char c[3] = "xyz"` and `char c[1] = "1"`?

Comment: The code doesn't compile — there's a semicolon missing after the first line.  Neither `c` nor `d` is a string; neither has enough space for the null byte that terminates the string.  Therefore, you're encountering undefined behaviour when you try to treat them as strings.  If you've been given `c` and can't make it into a string (e.g. `char c[] = "12345";`), then you'll need to be more careful with `d` — it could be defined as `char d[3] = "";` for example.  Lesson to learn: ensure there's enough space for the null terminator in strings, and don't treat byte arrays (non-strings) as strings.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler this was a toy example...'c' is something being given to  me say like this. I just want to extract some indices..is it possible? Or do I have to write 'c' properly?

Comment: @DuttaA "I just want to extract some indices" --> Do you want to exact the indices or the array values at those indices?

Comment: There are lots of ways to extract information from `c` — but you have to make sure that if you treat something as a string, it actually is a string.  I outlined how to make `d` into a string (by making it bigger and initializing it to 'all bytes zero').  You could just set `d[2] = '\0';` and not initialize the `d` — but you still need it to be at least an array of size 3.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica array value at those indices i.e., if somehow i can get `{c[3],c[4]}`, then I can use `atoi`

Comment: @DuttaA Still waiting on [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77093937/extract-characters-from-char-array-in-c?noredirect=1#comment135908005_77093937).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am just trying to extract a last few indices ad converting to a number. I have just shown one approach which I thought should give a correct solution. But my main goal is given 'c' extract a few indices and then use `atoi`.

Comment: @DuttaA You cannot use `atoi()` on `{c[3],c[4]}` as `{c[3],c[4]}` is not a _string_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica So I will be sent a 'c' of the form "blablabla567", and I need to extract the last 3 indices and convert it to integer (I will be knowing how many of the last indices will be digits)

Comment: @DuttaA, Try `printf("%d\n", atoi((char [3]){c[3], c[4], 0}));`

Comment: If you're stuck with `char d[2];`, then you have to process the data differently — in fact, you don't use either `d` or `atoi()` at all and write a loop to extract the values from `c[3]` and `c[4]` (int value = (c[3] - '0') * 10 + (c[4] - '0');`.  This doesn't rely on `c` being a string (and doesn't use `d` at all).  How much variation is there in what you want to extract (what range of indices)?  Are you certain the byte array has bytes storing digits in the range you expect to extract from?  The constraints on what you're given and what you're allowed to use are not clear.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I guess one can do that....I was hoping for an elegant solution, instead of all this.

Comment: The TL;DR. As mentioned, to use `atoi` which wants a 0x00 terminated `char` array (which is a C "string"), do this: `char c[5] = "12345"; char d[3];  // increase space for terminator d[0] = c[3]; d[1] = c[4]; d[2] = 0;  // add nul terminator printf("%d\n", atoi(d));`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica has posted elegant solutions — but you've not explained what variations you want your code to handle, so it is hard to know what counts as elegant for the task on hand (because the task on hand is not clear).  For the code shown, `puts("45");` would be simple and effective.

Comment: @DuttaA Consider other wording than "of the form "blablabla567", and I need to extract the last 3 indices and convert it to integer".  The last 3 _indices_ are 9, 10, 11.  The last 3 `char`s, at those indices, are `'5'`, `'6'`, `'7'`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica by indices I do mean value at those indices. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a pointer to where the number starts, no need for intermediary arrays.

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
...
int extractNumber(const char* c, int n)
{
    // if you're not allowed to use strlen you can
    // easily roll your own
    size_t lenOfAlpha = strlen(c) - n;
    return atoi(c + lenOfAlpha);
}
```

Note, the above function only works when you have a valid *string*.  That is, a `char` array with a `NUL` terminator.  <strike>As mentioned in the comments, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) right from the start by not allocating enough room for the printable characters of the string plus the `NUL` terminator.</strike>

As @[chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux-reinstate-monica) pointed out in the comments, `char c[5] = "xyz45"` doesn't actually invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), [despite all of `-fsanitize=address`'s complaining](https://godbolt.org/z/odPznvxdx).  Instead, it initializes the array with the characters of the string literal and leaves off the `NUL` terminator.  The function only works if you have a string (a `NUL`-terminated `char` array), which I think was the intent.  To initialize `c` as a string, you must change `c` to

```c
char c[6] = "xyz45";
```

or better yet

```c
char c[] = "xyz45";
```

Both will work, but the second option puts the burden of calculating length on the compiler, which means you don't have to count plus it's easier to maintain in the future should the string ever change.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fjsxbcjes)

If you indeed intended to have only a `char` array, see chux's answer above.

Comment: Yes, but `c` in the question isn't a string and your code assumes that it is a string.  I grant you that `c` should be a string!

Comment: @yano.  OP has `char c[5] = "xyz45"`.  Calling `extractNumber(c, 2)` results in _undefined behavior_ as `strlen()` expects a pointer to a _string_, which OP's `char` array is not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler and chux OP will have a string as soon as the UB is fixed, which I think was made clear in the comments, and given the OP's usage of a double quotes to initialize the array, a string was the intent. If OP had done `char c[5] = {'x','y','z','4','5'}` then I would be in a complete agreement with both of you. `char[5]` is a typo or a misunderstanding on needing room for a NUL terminator.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica UB starts before my function call, but yes fair enough from both of you, I should have mentioned the UB in my answer originally.

Comment: "you invoke undefined behavior right from the start by not allocating enough room for the printable characters of the string plus the NUL terminator." is unclear as `char c[5] = "xyz45";` is not UB.  That is OK.  It is just that `c[]` does not contain a _string_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica shoving 6 characters into size 5 array isn't UB? [`-fsanitize=address`](https://godbolt.org/z/36P5Tj8G7) sure complains about it.

Comment: `char c[5] = "xyz45";` is not UB. It does not shove 6 characters into 5, but 5 into 5. "An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF-8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null character **if there is room** or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array." C23dr § 6.7.10 15

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica wow, glad I answered, that's news to me. All this time I figured it would overflow the array by appending a NUL even if there wasn't room, but just proved what you say is true looking in gdb. I wonder why `-fsanitize=address` complains about an overflow then if none occurs? Thank you for the correction, I will change my answer. That being said, I still think it's clear enough from the context that OP intended to use strings, so this answer still has merit.

Comment: Often code like `char c[5] = "xyz45";` _leads_ to an error when `c[]` is used as a _string_, hence `-fsanitize=address`.  Yet `char c[5] = "xyz45";` is itself OK when `c[]` is used as a "char array" as titled in the question.  I rarely use `-fsanitize=address` given such false errors.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica mind blown this morning, thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

> I only know the last `n` positions of the array are digits.

A simple loop suffices (assuming no overflow in `sum`):

```
char c[] = ... 
int len = ...  // length of the array
int n = ...   

int sum = 0;
for (int i = len - n; i < len; i++) {
  sum = sum * 10 + (c[i] - '0');
}
  
printf("%d\n", sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do as you requested (output "45").  Compiled and tested code -- please note the adds/edits:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* atoi() */

int main()
{
    char c[6] = "12345";  /* Size 6 -- provide room for terminating NUL*/
    char d[3];  /* Size 3 -- again, provide room for terminating NUL*/

    d[0] = c[3];
    d[1] = c[4];
    d[2] = '\0';  /* Add a teminating NUL (strings need this)*/

    printf("%d\n", atoi(d));  /* Output: "45" */

    /* This also Outputs "45"  Why is that?  (Left as an exercise for the OP)*/
    printf("%d\n", atoi(&c[3]));  
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could use `char d[] = {c[3], c[4], 0 };`.

Answer (score 1):

Confusion over whether there is or is not a C string involved.

The following shows a test harness that presumes the OP's "have an array of chars" is significant:

```
int extract( char *str, int len, int n ) {
    int v = 0;
    char *cp = str + len;

    for( int dec = 1; n-- && --cp >= str && isdigit( *cp ); dec *= 10 )
        v += (*cp - '0') * dec;

    return v;
}

int main( void ) {
    int i;

    char arr[][9] = {
        { 'f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r', '1', '2', '3' },
        { 'f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r', 'r', '4', '2' },
        { 'f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r', '5', '6', '7' },
    };

    for( i = 0; i < sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]; i++ )
        printf( "%d: %d\n", i + 1, extract( arr[i], sizeof arr[0], 3 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
1: 123
2: 42
3: 567
```