# in C, when I print string without '\0', why are Chinese characters printed, not ASCII?

Tags: c, string, memory, null

Why does `printf("%s")` print out Chinese characters?

```
char str[5] = "Hello";
printf("%s", str);
```

When I run this code, I got `"Hello儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆?"`.
I think the `printf("%s", str);` function starts with the address value represented by str and prints each byte as char until it meets the null character.
However, I understand that Chinese characters cannot be printed with one byte. Why is the Chinese character `儆` printed?

Does `printf("%s")` recognize memory as Unicode if it is out of char array?

Comment: That's your terminal interpretation of the values outside ASCII range.

Comment: "String without '\0'" is not a string. Attempt to print it causes Undefined Behavior. What actual behavior is depends on many parameters including your terminal emulator and OS  implementation details.

Comment: There are no strings without `\0`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72436704/what-are-null-terminated-strings

Comment: If you need to print a sequence of characters that's not a string, we can limit the size of the field using `%.*s` conversion, e.g. `printf("%.*s", sizeof str, str);`.

Comment: Your string literal is 6 bytes long including the null character. However, 'str' array size is 5 bytes. The behavior can change depending on the compiler settings, console coding page...etc.  You should allocate char arrays with size one more than the maximum literal size to ensure that the ending null character can be assigned. So str[6] should correct this issue.

Answer (score 3):

The code has undefined behavior, so anything can happen.

Here is a tentative explanation: `printf` outputs all bytes from the array and continues with whatever bytes follow in memory until a null byte is found.  These byte values can be anything and probably produce an invalid encoding for the terminal, which may be using UTF-8 or Big5 or some other local encoding scheme.  If your system uses a Chinese locale, the terminal might use the Chinese character `儆` (Jǐng), which means *warn* or *caution* to signal this invalid sequence to the user.

Given the output posted, there seems to be about 11 invalid sequences and a `0x3F` byte before a null byte, producing 11 *Jǐng* Chinese characters (Hànzì) and a `?`.

Running the code on a different system, compiled by a different compiler, using different options, or just at a different time may produce other output or even no output at all.

As commented by *Toby Spleight*, since it's undefined behaviour, the code may do something else instead of, or as well as, producing output. If you're lucky, it will raise `SIGSEGV` to help you diagnose the problem, for instance. If you're less lucky, it will appear to "work" until you ship the program to your customers...

Comment: And since it's undefined behaviour, the code may do something else instead of, or as well as, producing output.  If you're lucky, it will raise `SIGSEGV` to help you diagnose the problem, for instance.  If you're less lucky, it will appear to "work" until you ship the program to your customers....