# calculate the length of string by the function of strlen

Tags: c

```
  char arr[]={'a','b','c'};
  int len=strlen(arr);
```

I know that when the pointer of char meet the address of `'0'`, this function would stop running and return the length between the array's first address and the address of `'0'`.
But when I created one string by that way, I didn't put `'0'`. So the pointer of char maybe
keep moving to find the address of `'0'`. In this process , the pointer maybe made a error about out-of-bounds access.
So why this code didn't make warn to me or why this code didn't make error?

Comment: The code has undefined behavior.

Comment: Are you asking why the *compiler* didn't catch the purposely-authored undefined behavior your wrote?

Comment: While most of us surely understand what you're trying to express, it should be noted that `'0'` is not the same as the null-terminating character, `'\0'`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58526131/how-should-character-arrays-be-used-as-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often times, it is about managing expectations.

Let's start with a small thought experiment (or time travel back to the early days of computing), where there are no programming languages - just machine code. There, you would (with CPU specific instructions) write something like this to represent a string:

```
arr: db 'a','b','c'
strlen:                         ; RDI (pointer to string) -> RAX (length of string)
                                ; RAX length counter and return value
                                ; CL used for null character test
        xor RAX, RAX            ; set RAX to 0
strlen_loop:
        mov cl, [rdi]           ; load CL with the byte pointed to by argument
        test cl,cl
        jz strlen_loop_done
        inc rdi                 ; look at next byte in argument
        inc rax                 ; increment the length counter
        jmp strlen_loop
strlen_loop_done:
        ret                     ; rax contains a zero terminated strings length
```

Compared to that, writing the same function in C is much simpler.

- We do not have to care about register allotment (which register does what).
- We do not rely on the instruction set of a specific CPU
- We do not have to look up the "calling conventions" or ABI for the target system (argument passing conventions etc)

```c
size_t strlen(const char* s) {
  size_t l = 0;
  while (*s) {
    l++;
    s++;
  }
  return l;
}
```

The convention, that "strings" are just pointers to chars (bytes) with the null value terminator is admittedly quite arbitrary but "comes" with the C programming language. It is just a convention. The compiler itself knows nothing about it (oh well it does know to add a terminating null on string literals). But when calling `strlen()` it cannot distinguish the string case from the just a byte array case. Why? because there is no specific string type.

As such, it is just about as clever as the assembler code version I gave above. It relies on the "c-string-convention". The assembler does not check, nor does the C compiler, because - let's be honest, C's main accomplishments are the bullet items I gave above.

So if you manage your expectations, about the language C, think of it as: A slightly abstracted version of a glorified assembly language.

If you are annoyed about the c-string convention (after all, `strlen` is `O(n)` in time complexity), you can still come up with your own string type, maybe so:

```c
typedef struct String_tag {
  size_t length;
  char data[];
} String_t;
```

And write yourself helpers (to create a string on the heap) and macros (to create a string on the stack with `alloca` or something). And write your own string feature library around that type.

If you are just getting started with C, instead of tackling something bigger, I think this would be a good exercise for learning the language.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen()` only works correctly for zero-terminated character arrays, and what you have is not one.

What `len` returns for your program is entirely dependent on what happens to be in memory after the address `arr + 3`.

If there's a zero there, then you'll get 3. If there's other data before a zero, then you'll get another number. If you're unlucky and there's no zero (in your process's memory space), your program will crash with an out-of-bounds read.

For instance, the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char blarr[] = {'d', 'e', 'f'};
  char arr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
  int len = strlen(arr);
  printf("%d\n", len);
  return 0;
}
```

[*may* print 6, depending on how the compiler allocates `arr` and `blarr` on stack.](https://godbolt.org/z/7aqcK3rrM)

Your compiler doesn't warn about anything, because your program is technically correct – you're passing in a `char*` to `strlen`, that's fine – but it's not smart enough to detect that that `char*` isn't a zero-terminated string.

Answer (score 0):

> So the pointer of char maybe keep moving to find the address of '0'.In this process , the pointer maybe made a error about out-of-bounds access.

Yes, that's exactly what happened.

> So why this code didn't make warn to me or why this code didn't make error?

Because the declaration

```
char arr[] = {'a','b','c'};
```

is perfectly valid.  You haven't given the compiler any indication that you intend to use `arr` as a string.

A somewhat more interesting case is if you were to write

```
char arr[3] = "abc";
```

Due to a historical quirk, this is perfectly legal C, although it creates exactly the same array `arr` and will have exactly the same problem if you pass it to to `strlen`.  Here, though, I believe some compilers *will* warn, and it would certainly be an appropriate warning, since the feature is debatable, and rarely deliberately used.

Comment: "Here, though, some compilers will warn" Which compilers would that be? I just tested latest gcc, clang, icx with `-Wall -Wextra`, no warnings. Same in MSVC. This quirk is particularly nasty just because most compilers will _not_ warn.

Comment: @Lundin Good question.  I had already tried with gcc and clang with -Wextra and was surprised to get no warning.  I *thought* I'd heard of this warning existing, but maybe it was just wishful thinking.

Comment: @SteveSummit it is an error in C++.

Comment: @SteveSummit (*cough*) Maybe you need to use a [C/C++ compiler](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420340/584518) ;)  j/k  But well, these kind of super-subtle differences between C and C++ would be one of the many reasons to try to keep the languages separated on SO.

Comment: I just found a C compiler that does warn. Codewarrior for MCUs in C mode gives "resulting string is not zero terminated" as a warning. This compiler is known to be picky in general.