# c, why i can't print all elements of my array

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, initialization, string-literals

I'm writing a simple program in c, **that prints all elements of an array.**
The array is

```
char op[2][50] = {"option1", "option2"};
```

the program is

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char spaces[6] = "      ";
    int choice;
    char op[2][50] = {"option1", "option2"};

    printf("\n\n\t=========== OPTIONS ===========\n\n\t");
    for (int i;i<sizeof(op)/sizeof(op[0]);i++) {printf("%s[%d]: %s\n\t",spaces,i+1,op[i]);}
    printf("\n\t\t%s[?]: ",spaces);
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    
    if (choice==1) {firstFunction();} //i've declared this function, but here isn't important

    return 0;
}
```

So, the problem is that **the options arent printed**.
output:

```
=========== VIDEO TOOLS ===========


               [?]:
```

the problem is essentially that if statement, because *i've tried to add other printf up and down it and them works.*
Also, that if statement worked before some changes to the program, so *the problem can be other lines of code(?)*

**i'm a beginner with c**, so please not expose complex solutions. thanks

Comment: What is the value of `i`?

Comment: The size of `spaces` is to small to hold the string you want it to hold. Remember that strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** strings*. That means a string of six characters really need space for seven, to be able to hold the terminator. Drop the size-specification for `spaces` to solve that issue: `char spaces[] = "      ";`

Comment: Make it a habit to _end_ your printf lines with `\n` rather than to begin with them. Because `\n` does not only change the line, it may also flush the stdout on some systems. Failing to flush stdout might cause the output to appear in a strange order or go missing.

Comment: `i'm a beginner with c`... Then you still have time to NOT get used to using (and wasting hours chasing problems arising from using)  `scanf( )` Run away! Figure out how to use `fgets()` and deal with the "line at a time" input it can deliver. Don't be lazy... Too many SO questions because of abuse and misuse of `scanf()`... Not recommended...

Comment: @Fe2O3 i've tried fgets! but i have a problem.. if i use two consecutive fgets, the first fgets doesn't work.. do you know how can i solve?

Comment: `the first fgets doesn't work..` Hardly the case. `fgets( )` is used in millions of programs around the world and it **works**... No, I cannot solve your problem because I do not read minds... If you make a serious effort and experience difficulties, post the (small) code example as a new question to SO and get **expert** advice on what's wrong and how to fix it... Stay away from `scanf( )`... It _can_ work if the input conforms to the programmer's expectations. Otherwise, it doesn't...

Comment: Rather, don't waste a lot of time learning console I/O. People stopped using such almost 30 years ago, with the advent of GUIs. Just regard console stuff as quick & dirty debugging aid, not something to use in production code.

Answer (score 0):

`for (int i;i<sizeof(op)/sizeof(op[0]);i++)`

You do not initialize the `i` variable and it is an Undefined Behaviour (UB)

It should be:

```
for (int i = 0;i<sizeof(op)/sizeof(op[0]);i++)
```

or better (using the correct type for sizes and positive indexes)

```
for (size_t i = 0;i<sizeof(op)/sizeof(op[0]);i++)
```

To print `size_t` use `%zu` format

Also, remember that C string is terminated by the null terminating character. So you need to add one more character than seen in the string literal. ("123" requires 4 characters)  `spaces` array is too short to accommodate `"      "`. `char spaces[] = "      ";`

Answer (score 0):

Lots of bugs. Summary of things mentioned in comments:

- `i` is used while uninitialized, set it to zero.
- `char spaces[6] = "      ";` is too small, see [How should character arrays be used as strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58526131/how-should-character-arrays-be-used-as-strings).
- Make it a habit to *end* your printf lines with `\n` rather than to begin with them. Because `\n` does not only change the line, it may also flush the stdout on some systems. Failing to flush stdout might cause the output to appear in a strange order or go missing.

Also in case these are read-only strings, then consider using a 1D array of pointers instead, since that's more flexible and memory efficient:

```
const char* op[2] = {"option1", "option2"};
```

Comment: Good to point out that "specifying 6" was a bad move. Better to let the compiler measure things. But, then, to set the size of the array of pointers to `2` and dictate to the compiler that dimension??? Odd...

Answer (score 0):

This array declaration where the number of elements is specified explicitly:

```
char spaces[6] = "      ";
```

is error prone. The array does not contain a string because the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string literal used as an initializer is not stored in the array `spaces`. The size of the string literal is equal to `7` not to `6`.

So it is safer to write:

```
char spaces[] = "      ";
```

Or as you are not going to change the array then it will be better to write:

```
const char *spaces = "      ";
```

In this declaration of the two-dimensional array:

```
char op[2][50] = {"option1", "option2"};
```

you explicitly specified that the array contains two elements. So using the expression `i<sizeof(op)/sizeof(op[0])` does not make a great sense.

Either introduce a named constant before the declaration of the array, like for example:

```
enum { N = 2 };
char op[N][50] = {"option1", "option2"};
```

and then use the expression:

```
i < N
```

in the for loop. Or declare the array like:

```
char op[][50] = {"option1", "option2"};
```

and after the declaration introduce a named constant like:

```
const size_t N = sizeof( op )/sizeof( op[0] );
```

and use the constant in the for loop where by the way you forgot to initialize the variable i

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
{
    printf("%s[%zu]: %s\n\t",spaces,i+1,op[i]);
}
```

As the variable i now has the type size_t then you have to use the conversion specifier `%zu` instead of `%d` in the call of `printf`.

It will be safer to rewrite this code snippet

```
scanf("%d",&choice);

if (choice==1) {firstFunction();} // I've declared this function, but here isn't important
```

The following way:

```
if ( scanf("%d",&choice) == 1 && choice==1 ) 
{
    firstFunction();
} // I've declared this function, but here isn't important
```