# Why is the string length of buf1[12] = "hello world?" 13?

Tags: c, strlen

I have the code and output below, why are the string length of `buf1` and `buf2`/`buf3` different?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buf1[12] = "hello world?";
    char buf2[] = "hello world?";
    char buf3[13] = "hello world?";
    int buf1length, buf2length, buf3length;

    buf1length = strlen(buf1);
    buf2length = strlen(buf2);
    buf3length = strlen(buf3);

    printf("buf1length: %d\n", buf1length);
    printf("buf2length: %d\n", buf2length);
    printf("buf3length: %d\n", buf3length);

    printf("buf1: %lu\n",sizeof(buf1));
    printf("buf2: %lu\n",sizeof(buf2));
    printf("buf3: %lu\n",sizeof(buf3));
}
```

Output:

```
buf1length: 13
buf2length: 12
buf3length: 12
buf1: 12
buf2: 13
buf3: 13
```

Since the `strlen()` function doesn’t count the null character `\0`, and the size of `buf1` is 12,

how come is the string length of `buf1[12]` 13?

Comment: `Since the strlen() function doesn’t count the null character ‘\0’, and the size of buf1 is 12` there __is__ no `\0` character.

Comment: The string assigned to buf1 requires 13 characters, including the null terminator. You have reserved only 12 characters for the string. You have created a buffer overflow resulting in undefined behavior, making your program erroneous.

Comment: @JimRogers An extremely niche caveat of C array initialization is that an array initialized by a string literal which perfectly fits *without* the null-terminating byte **will** be initialized without the null-terminating byte (i.e., when `strlen(string_lit) == sizeof buffer`). The UB comes from calling `strlen` on a non-null-terminated buffer. The initialization of `buf1` is well defined. See: https://godbolt.org/z/qh34G68PE

Comment: With clang cant even compiling: /cplayground/code.cpp:5:21: error: initializer-string for char array is too long
    char buf1[12] = "hello world?";

Comment: @user_0 That shouldn't be a fatal error. Did you turn on the option that converts warnings to errors?

Comment: String functions only work properly with null-terminated strings. Since there isn't room for the null terminator, you get undefined behavior when calling `strlen()`.

Comment: @Jim Rogers You are right! The code  --- char buf1[12] = "hello world?"; perror("array"); --- said array: Undefined error: 0. Thank you very much! Thank you everyone for your comment!

Comment: @Mary `perror` works entirely based on the current value of [`errno`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). Language features such as initialization will not influence this in any way - your observation is misleading. Additionally, Jim is incorrect on the *source* of the buffer overflow - it's `strlen(buf1)`, not the initialization (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77160667/why-is-the-string-length-of-buf112-hello-world-13#comment136026743_77160667)).

Comment: @Oka, thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58526131/how-should-character-arrays-be-used-as-strings also has answers to explain the reason.

Comment: @Barmar, I used cplayground.com 
clang++ -o /cplayground/cplayground /cplayground/code.cpp -I/cplayground/include -L/cplayground/lib -std=c++20 -O0 -Wall -no-pie -lm -pthread

Comment: @user_0 I was thinking of C -- may C++ is more strict.

Comment: @Mary "how come is the string length of buf1[12] 13?" --> `strlen()` expect a pointer to a _string_.  `buf[]` is **not** a _string_ as it lacks a _null character_.   Result: _undefined behavior_ (UB).  Anything may happen.  Only use `strlen()` with pointers to _strings_.

Comment: @chux Thank you for your comment! But  1 )char buf[13] = "hello world?"; printf("%lu\n", strlen(buf));
    2) char *bf = "hello world?"; printf("%lu\n", strlen(bf));
   3) printf("%lu\n", strlen("hello world?")); all work!

Comment: @Mary So those work, OK.  Those `strlen()` calls all examine a _string_.  Why do you expect `char buf1[12] = "hello world?"; strlen(buf1)`, which seeks a _null character_, to work?  It does not find a _null character_ in `buf1`. It does not know how long the data is that it can examine.  What do you expect code to do when it searches for a _null character_ and does not find it in the first 12 bytes - somehow know it should stop even though it does not know the length of the memory it can examine?

Comment: `buf1` is not a string. So the concept of string length does not apply, and `strlen(buf1)` is undefined behaviour. You claim the code happens to work when you run it, which 1) you can't count on since it's undefined behaviour, and 2) isn't true, since it can't possibly print the length of the string in `buf1` since there's no string in `buf1`. It's like saying you successfully measured the heart rate of a Honda Civic.