# unsigned char * changing length depending on OS/Compiler in c++

Tags: c++, linux, g++, typecasting-operator

I found a strange bug in my code. My code is should  be cross compatible with windows and linux. I found when I compile my program windows mingw, it adds 6 bytes to a specific data type/variable when getting its length.

I don't know how to explain much further so here's what i found

```
int paddingSize =  strlen((char*)cipherText);
```

I defined **cipherText** as a unsigned char * which is an array of raw encrypted aes-256 bytes.
when the snippet above is compiled on linux, if the array size is 16 bytes, the int will be 16.
Being compiled on windows however, there will be on offset of exactly +6 bytes every time. To combat this I was using the snippet below

```
int paddingSize =  strlen((char*)cipherText) - 6;
```

I was wondering why this could be? Is this a compiler issue such as mingw vs G++ (GNU)? or is it an architecture problem? Could this also be a data type problem where type casting is ruining it on one OS but not the other?

I have tried different things but all came out with confusing answer.

Comment: Please post the full code with [MCVE]. Are you compiling C __or__ C++? If C++, do not tag c. The simplest answer is, _your_ code has a bug, `y` or `cipherText` do not point to a memory region terminated with a zero byte.

Comment: Do `cipherText` and `y` point to a null-terminated string?

Comment: The edit didn't provide the full code, or the declaration of `y`. The code snippet is using cipherText, but the text is talking about y. Which one is it?

Comment: A string is a [null terminated array of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58526131/how-should-character-arrays-be-used-as-strings). It looks like `cipherText` isa not a string and you cannot determine its size with `strlen`.

Comment: Your coding style is out-dated. Any code still using raw pointers, "C" style strings and calls like strlen should not be used anymore. Use std::string (or std::vector<std::uint8_t> in case you have '\0' characters in your cyphertext (which is very likely). What source do you use to learn C++ from, it is likely outdated as well. As a list side note your string length isn't an `int` but a `std:size_t` (be precise in the types you use, see [`std::strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen))

Comment: I'm betting problem is that you string contains none ASCII characters and different encoding used by compiler leads to different lengths of this string measured in bytes. Or like answer suggest missing terminating zero in code  leading to UB.

Comment: @MarekR not to mention all other "control characters" the string could contain which might screw up stream operations.

Comment: @PepijnKramer well in my case "c" strings are necessary due to that fact that i am using libraries made in c. Im only using c++ for some specific data types and other functionality. Specifically im using an aes 256 library which returns an unsigned char * array. an unsigned char is necessary for the algorithm to work.

Comment: No that's not true you can use vector's `data()` method to get a pointer to the data which you can forward to "C". So you can use std::vector<unsigned char>.  For the returned char* you can use a std::string_view (construct from char* and length). Also interesting to know is does the library just return a char* or also size info (if not things get difficult) and who onws that memory are you supposed to free the memory later? If so take ownership by using std::unique_ptr.  Summary write as much code as you can in current C++ only adapt at the boundaries.

Comment: Another option is to switch to a C++ aes library completely, Just make sure you have unit test (which you should have anyway)

Comment: @NotAidan `int paddingSize=strlen((char*)cipherText);` -- *I have tried different things but all came out with confusing answer.* -- As mentioned, `strlen` is a function that starts at the address you give it, and counts the characters until a null byte is encountered.   Don't use functions that rely on null-termination such as `strlen` if the strings are going to contain embedded nulls, or if the size information is known to you beforehand.  I bet that you knew already what the length of `ciphertext` was (you set the length, or you got the info from a function), so `strlen` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen` counts the bytes until it finds a `'\0'` character. If your `y` points to an array of chars with length of 16, the result of `strlen` simply gives you the number of chars until the first `'\0`' was found, fully independent how long your array is! It is also possible that your prog simply crashes because you access memory behind the array.

You can't get the length of an array from a pointer to char.

The size of a variable can be taken by using `sizeof()`. In case of a pointer it returns the size of the pointer itself, which is typically 8, depending on machine type you are running.

You should avoid typecasts at all