# How can I make an array composed of other arrays in C?

Tags: c

I just started programming. I want to make it so that the program writes a 4-digit input in LCD format, but there seems to be a problem with the way I make the `lcd` array.

The code identifies the individual values of the entry, associates them to variables, then puts said variables into a list. What follows are the different numbers from zero to nine written in LCD, then those numbers are put into an array (that is where I suspect the problem lies), and finally a loop that associates the values of each variable to an element of the final array, and prints the LCD number.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a, b, c, d;
    printf("Enter 4 digit number:\n");
    scanf("%1d%1d%1d%1d", &a, &b, &c, &d);

    int digit[4];
    digit[0]=a;
    digit[1]=b;
    digit[2]=c;
    digit[3]=d;

    char zero [4][4] = {
        " _ \n",
        "| |\n",
        "|_|\n",
        " \n"
    };

    char one [4][4] = {
        " \n",
        "  \n|",
        "  \n|",
        " \n"
    };

    char two [4][4] = {
        " _ \n",
        " _|\n",
        "|_ \n",
        " \n"
    };

    char three [4][4] = {
        " _ \n",
        " _|\n",
        " _|\n",
        " \n"
    };

    char four [4][4] = {
        " \n",
        "|_|\n",
        "  |\n",
        " \n"
    };

    char five [4][4] = {
        " _ \n",
        "|_ \n",
        " _|\n",
        " \n"
    };

    char six [4][4] = {
        " _ \n",
        "|_ \n",
        "|_|\n",
        " \n"
    };

    char seven [4][4] = {
        " _ \n",
        "| |\n",
        "  |\n",
        " \n"
    };

    char eight [4][4] = {
        " _ \n",
        "|_|\n",
        "|_|\n",
        " \n"
    };

    char nine [4][4] = {
        " _ \n",
        "|_|\n",
        " _|\n",
        " \n"
    };

    char* lcd[10][4][4] = {
        {zero[0], one[0], two[0], three[0], four[0], five[0], six[0], seven[0], eight[0], nine[0]}, // First row
        {zero[1], one[1], two[1], three[1], four[1], five[1], six[1], seven[1], eight[1], nine[1]}, // Second row
        {zero[2], one[2], two[2], three[2], four[2], five[2], six[2], seven[2], eight[2], nine[2]}, // Third row
        {zero[3], one[3], two[3], three[3], four[3], five[3], six[3], seven[3], eight[3], nine[3]}  // Fourth row
    };

    for(int i =0;i<4;i++) {
        for(int k =0;k<4;k++){
            printf("%s", lcd[digit[i]][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried redefining the array in multiple ways, but nothing seems to get the job done correctly.

Comment: You should not try to print those as strings since they have no nul terminator. Perhaps unusual to put the newlines with the data too. Better to put that in `printf`.

Comment: Well, for one thing, you have over-complicated your arrays. You don't need multi-dimensional arrays to accomplish what you want. `zero`..`nine` can be simpler 1D `char*[]` arrays, and `lcd` can be a simpler 1D `char**[]` array. Also, on a side note, your `one` array is formatted incorrectly, the `|` characters are in the wrong places.

Comment: [How should character arrays be used as strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58526131/how-should-character-arrays-be-used-as-strings)

Comment: And well, this is not how 7-segment displays work... they have a bunch of LEDs forming segements. You light them up by enabling the corresponding LEDs, not by sending out text.

Answer (score 1):

First, your arrays for the numbers aren't big enough to hold the strings they're initialized with.  The second dimension has to be at least 5 to store the terminating null byte, i.e.:

```
char nine [4][5] = {
    " _ \n",
    "|_|\n",
    " _|\n",
    " \n"
};
```

Then you need to declare `lcd` as an array of pointers to arrays:

```
char (*lcd[])[5] = { zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine };
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inner `char[4]` only has room for 3 characters + the null terminator and you sometimes have a character too many. By removing `\n` you can make them all fit - but you also need to make each row for each character the same width, or else they won't be align properly when you print them next to each other. One example could look like this:

```c
const char zero [4][4] = {
    " _ ", // 3 chars + null terminator everywhere
    "| |",
    "|_|",
    "   "
};
```

Then your `lcd` array could simply be pointers to these arrays:

```cpp
typedef const char(*digarr)[4];

const digarr lcd[] = {
    zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine
};
```

Printing would be looping through each row with an inner loop to print each digit:

```c
void lcdprint(const char *digits) {
    for(int row = 0; row < 4; ++row) {
        for(const char *d = digits; *d; ++d) {
            char dig = *d;
            if(dig >= '0' && dig <= '9') {
                fputs(lcd[dig - '0'][row], stdout);
            } else { // invalid digit
                fputs("   ", stdout);
            }
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4KoxeTjex)

Answer (score 0):

Use array of pointers to char, then array of pointers to arrays of pointers to char:

```
void print(const char *str)
{
    char *zero[] = {
        " _ ",
        "| |",
        "|_|",
        "   "
    };

    char *one[] = {
        "   ",
        "  |",
        "  |",
        "   "
    };

    char *two[] = {
        " _ ",
        " _|",
        "|_ ",
        "   "
    };

    char *three[] = {
        " _ ",
        " _|",
        " _|",
        "   "
    };

    char *four[] = {
        "   ",
        "|_|",
        "  |",
        " "
    };

    char *five[] = {
        " _ ",
        "|_ ",
        " _|",
        "   "
    };

    char *six[] = {
        " _ ",
        "|_ ",
        "|_|",
        "   "
    };

    char *seven[] = {
        " _ ",
        "| |",
        "  |",
        "   "
    };

    char *eight[] = {
        " _ ",
        "|_|",
        "|_|",
        "   "
    };

    char *nine[] = {
        " _ ",
        "|_|",
        " _|",
        "   "
    };

    char *nothing[] = {
        "   ",
        "   ",
        "   ",
        "   ",
    };

    char *(*digits[])[sizeof(nine) / sizeof(nine[0])] = {&zero, &one, &two, &three, &four, &five, &six, &seven, &eight, &nine, &nothing};

    size_t len = strlen(str);
    for(size_t row = 0; row < sizeof(nine) / sizeof(nine[0]); row++)
    {
        for(size_t pos = 0; pos < len; pos++)
        {
            printf("%s ", (*digits[isdigit(str[pos]) ? str[pos] - '0' : 10])[row]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


void printInt(unsigned int x)
{
    char buff[30];

    sprintf(buff, "%u", x);
    print(buff);
}

int main(void)
{
    print("0123456789");
    printInt(54765);
    print("012sdfhgsdf3456789");
}
```

output (printing empty space if char is not digit):

```
 _       _   _       _   _   _   _   _  
| |   |  _|  _| |_| |_  |_  | | |_| |_| 
|_|   | |_   _|   |  _| |_|   | |_|  _| 
                                      
 _       _   _   _  
|_  |_| | | |_  |_  
 _|   |   | |_|  _| 
                  
 _       _                                   _       _   _   _   _   _  
| |   |  _|                                  _| |_| |_  |_  | | |_| |_| 
|_|   | |_                                   _|   |  _| |_|   | |_|  _|
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8EoPhxKej

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you happen upon a real [7-segement display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display) in the real world outside academic exercises, you'd rather define each digit as a bitfield of active/inactive segments, then activate those accordingly using GPIO ports. (Often bit-banging through shift registers or specialized drivers.)

Given the definition of segment names from the linked wikipedia, we'd form a bit-field and not some strings, for example like this:

```
const uint8_t digits [10] =
{
  [0] = SEG_A|SEG_B|SEG_C|SEG_D|SEG_E|SEG_F,
  [1] = SEG_B|SEG_C,
  // ...
};
```

This saves a little bit of memory compared to strings, no matter if we are dealing with a real 7 segment display - which has no use for strings anyway, or some `printf`-based "simulator".

Complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/*
  7 segment display
  Definition of segments from wikipedia:

  _    A
 |_| F G B
 |_| E D C
*/

typedef enum : uint8_t
{
  SEG_A = 1U<<0,  
  SEG_B = 1U<<1,
  SEG_C = 1U<<2,
  SEG_D = 1U<<3,
  SEG_E = 1U<<4, 
  SEG_F = 1U<<5,
  SEG_G = 1U<<7,
} seg_t;


void activate_7seg (uint8_t digit)
{
  const uint8_t digits [10] =
  {
    [0] = SEG_A|SEG_B|SEG_C|SEG_D|SEG_E|SEG_F,
    [1] = SEG_B|SEG_C,
    // ...
  };

  uint8_t bitfield = digits[digit];
  printf(" %c \n",   bitfield & SEG_A ? '_' : ' ');
  printf("%c%c%c\n", bitfield & SEG_F ? '|' : ' ',
                     bitfield & SEG_G ? '_' : ' ',
                     bitfield & SEG_B ? '|' : ' ');
  printf("%c%c%c\n", bitfield & SEG_E ? '|' : ' ',
                     bitfield & SEG_D ? '_' : ' ',
                     bitfield & SEG_C ? '|' : ' ');
}

int main(void)
{
  activate_7seg(0);
  activate_7seg(1);
}
```

This can now easily be turned into embedded system code for a real-world display, just by swapping out the printf calls for GPIO.